# Vue router check if direct route

Tags: vue.js

As per documentation,

```
         `router.go(-1)`
```

will go back by one record

How to know if the url (or router) has been directly accessed or has history so I can use

```
         `router.go(1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
   const history = window.history.length;
   if (history > 2) {
      this.$router.go(-1);
    } else {
      this.$router.push(`/`);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The history array is tight to the `browser session history (that is, the pages visited in the tab or frame that the current page is loaded in)` as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

This means that hard refreshes or direct navigations in the same tab will have the `history` array filled with previous entries. And the `window.history.length` check will fail.

Therefore I think the VUE way of detecting this would be using the [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

Before entering a new route, we can check if the previous URL is a known app route. And update a store property (`directRoute` here, that is defaulted to `null`) accordingly:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const previousRoutes = from.matched.length;
    const isJustLanding = store.state.directRoute === null && previousRoutes === 0;

    store.commit("updateDirectRoute", isJustLanding);

    next();
}
```